# Every time I need to add libraries

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, push, pull

I am developing automated tests  on Intellij idea.
I work on two computers, at work I have a Mac, and Windows at home.
Every day after I finish working at work, I make add, commit and push to git.
When I get home and do pull, every time I should to add libraries , And the same thing when I get to work after I've made a push to git at home.
Is this normal ? Or is there a way to solve this?

I use libraries for automation test like : java-client and more

Comment: Hi Michael, welcome to Stack Overflow. Some parts are a bit confused here. Could you explicit / reformulate "every time I should to add libraries"?

Answer (score 0):

You can [share the libraries and the project configuration](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839) in the same repository via the version control. This way the project will work out of the box when you update/checkout it on any machine and open in the IDE.

If your project is managed by Gradle or Maven, this will save you from storing the binary dependencies in the version control repository. Refreshing the project in the IDE will download all the new dependencies via the build system of your choice.